# Simple Ajax call posting back entire page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to call and return data from a controller action asynchronously using Ajax.

In my example below, when clicking on the `ActionLink` it posts back to a new page with just "Hello!".  How can I get this to just update the div?

**Controller:**

```
public class HelloAsyncController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Say Hello", "Hello", "HelloAsync",
    new AjaxOptions()
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "HelloDiv"
    })

<div id="HelloDiv"></div>
```

**Includes in _Layout.cshtml:**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I am using MVC 5.

Comment: Have you tried passing `controller` in action link

Comment: @Satpal:  I have tried that.  Post edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Say Hello", 
    "Hello", 
    "HelloAsync", 
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId="HelloDiv",
        HttpMethod = "Get",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
    })
```

I thing that issue might be

> The contents of the UpdateTargetID must be in a partial view and that
>   partial view needs to be called from the Controller Action. . You need to use a
>   partial view.

Also check

> Check if files MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js are really
>   present in ../../Scripts folder.

Comment: I have included the controller. Sorry, edited my post to include it.

Comment: I have tried with a PartialView too with the same result.  I don't have  `MicrosoftAjax.js` or `MicrosoftMvcAjax.js`.  I read that they were replaced with `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`?